# content select option based on previous select option angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i want to create 2 select option which the content of the other one selected option based to previous option. here is my html

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="y">
                <option value="1">a</option>
                <option value="2">b</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="z">
                <option ng-repeat = "x in list" value="{{x.idproduct}}">{{x.descproduct}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

but there is error, the other select option wont showing the option like in this picture[image]

here is my js file

```
if ($scope.y === 1) {
         $scope.list = [
          {idproduct:"13", descproduct:"cc"},
          {idproduct:"14", descproduct:"dd"}
         ]; 
       }
       if ($scope.y === 2) {
         $scope.list = [
          {idproduct:"15", descproduct:"ee"}
         ]; 
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `change` event so that your list gets updated at the time that your value is updated. Plus your `===` can cause an issue. With `===` your string value is being compared to integers 1 and 2.
Here is a plunker: [ng-change for change in dropdown](https://plnkr.co/edit/egn1nPL4IYoDE09E7bYF?p=preview)

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="y" ng-change="updateList()">
     <option value="1">a</option>
     <option value="2">b</option>
</select>
$scope.updateList()={
if ($scope.y == 1) {
         $scope.list = [
          {idproduct:"13", descproduct:"cc"},
          {idproduct:"14", descproduct:"dd"}
         ]; 
       }
       if ($scope.y == 2) {
         $scope.list = [
          {idproduct:"15", descproduct:"ee"}
         ]; 
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of your option is String `value="2"`

And you're comparing it to an Integer `if ($scope.y === 2)`

You should compare it like `if ($scope.y === '2')` or `if (parseInt($scope.y) === 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Create a function and put your Js code in that function and call function on ng-change of the first dropdown. Here you if condition executes once during app initialization. So by triggering ng-change we can call function and update the lists based on the selection.